# send a key to a game window not foreground

Tags: c++, winapi

I am playing a game run by directX,I send a keybord's key to the game window by postMessage(),but I have to foreground this window before I send the key otherwise it will fail.

`::SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

::PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, keyCode, key_param_1);
Sleep(20);
::PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, keyCode, key_param_2);`

Is there any way to send a key without foreground the window? (ps:the game's name is 《天龙八部》)

the codes I paste above is work very well. The only dificiency is that I have to foreground the window.I open two window for this game concurrently,now I add a mutex to control two window,it work well,but the chaneing-over between two windows is too frequent,I think it's bad for my eyes;This technoloty is not for business,I swear to the god.I find a game's software is already complete that send a key to this game not foreground,but the auther of this software was caught by the police and face a lawsuit 5 months ago.I had use his software for 4 years,but now his software is freezed.So I want do this rely myself.

Comment: Seems MMORPG. It is possible that the authors of game and other players of it do not want you to fool it and to program bots for it. Read your service agreement you may become banned doing that.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=35513)

Comment: If you use `PostMessage`, you don't worry about whether it's a foreground window, because it specifies `hwnd`.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT The game was protected by something,PostMessage() will not work if not foreground.

Comment: This is caused by the game window. It has nothing to do with the api called. In other words, it is set by the game manufacturer to prevent this kind of behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Input can only be send to the window that is in focus (cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(computing))

However there are techniques to circumvent this :

- Microsofts own 'tutorial' : **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-simulate-mouse-and-keyboard-events-in-code**
- https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/sending-a-key-to-a-window-thats-not-in-focus-c-program/
- http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?555185-RESOLVED-how-use-SendInput()-for-a-non-focus-window

Comment: None of that is useful. The question is tagged [tag:c++], so linking to a solution that is tied to the .NET framework won't help. The other links solve the problem by ignoring the pre-condition.